# Value Error on preprocessing.MinMaxScaler().fit_transform()

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, jupyter

Help me understand what i am doing wrong here

```
# Read Data
dataset = pd.read_csv("PS_20174392719_1491204439457_log.csv")
dataset = dataset.iloc[1:50000]
print (dataset.head())
```

Output for above code,

```
   step      type    amount     nameOrig  oldbalanceOrg  newbalanceOrig  \
1     1   PAYMENT   1864.28  C1666544295        21249.0        19384.72   
2     1  TRANSFER    181.00  C1305486145          181.0            0.00   
3     1  CASH_OUT    181.00   C840083671          181.0            0.00   
4     1   PAYMENT  11668.14  C2048537720        41554.0        29885.86   
5     1   PAYMENT   7817.71    C90045638        53860.0        46042.29   

      nameDest  oldbalanceDest  newbalanceDest  isFraud  isFlaggedFraud  
1  M2044282225             0.0             0.0        0               0  
2   C553264065             0.0             0.0        1               0  
3    C38997010         21182.0             0.0        1               0  
4  M1230701703             0.0             0.0        0               0  
5   M573487274             0.0             0.0        0               0
```

When i run below code, i get a value error

```
# Scale dataset and split into fraud and non-fraud instances
x = dataset.drop(["isFraud"], axis=1)
y = dataset["isFraud"].values 

x_scale = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(x.values)
x_norm, x_fraud = x_scale[y == 0], x_scale[y == 1]



ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'PAYMENT'
```

What exactly am i doing wrong?

Comment: try `x_scale = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(x)`

Comment: tried that but still shoots a Value Error

Comment: You are trying to Scale non-numeric value columns like type, nameOrig etc. Exclude them.

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: what is your error?

Comment: @I'mahdi ValueError : could not convert string to float: 'PAYMENT'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

- Drop columns that have string values because you want to scale numbers
- Convert columns that have numbers to float (maybe your number is saved as `string` in the `.csv` file.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
x = dataset.drop(columns=['type', 'nameOrig', 'nameDest', 'isFraud'])).astype(np.float32)
x_scale = scaler.fit_transform(x)
```

Comment: This worked but i fail to understand what happened

Comment: @RoyThande, welcome,  I drop the columns that have `string` and convert the numbers to `float` with `astype(np.float32)`, maybe your number saved in .csv as `string`